# Location manager and speed in Android?

Tags: android

In my application I used location manager to get the latitude and longitude. But while roaming the “connection” to the map location does not “connect” with the most recent location immediately. Sometimes it takes up to five restarts before it works. Other times it takes more.

Here is what I am doing,

```
LocationManager locationManager;              
String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;         
locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context);     
String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;      

Location location =locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);          
updateWithNewLocation(location);               

myLocationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(
                        Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

myLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();

myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,myLocationListener);
```

And in onLocationChanged

```
double Lat = argLocation.getLatitude();         
double Long = argLocation.getLongitude();      

Longitude = Double.toString(Long);         
Latitude = Double.toString(Lat);
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you rephrase "the connection to the map location does not connect with the most recent location immediately." ? What exactly do you mean ? Is your locationListener onLocationChanged not kicking in ?

Comment: @ddewaele I get the GPS location but while roaming it do not reflect the most recent location so My app requirement is to get the most recent location to provide the emergency service.

Answer (score 0):

I notice you're using the GPS provider which does take longer to locate itself in some situations. I'd recommend an intial location using the network provider:

```
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

I've had rather precise results with this initial value and it serves as a good starting point while the user continues working with the app while better results become available in a background process. [This guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) provides some helpful best practices.